# Automatic field creation for Bulk Write operations mongodb

Tags: java, mongodb, aggregation-framework, bulkinsert

Hi i need to  execute bulk insert with  automatic field createdon [ timestamp ] ,

as of now i am manually creating createdon timestamp and set it into document and then calling insert method.
 for inserting single document this is ok,

But this is not efficient for executing bulkinsert with lacks of records  ,

Can anyone show how to execute bulkInsert data with automatic field
or  suggest some  better solution for creating automatic field in mongodb

Actual Data for BulkWrite insert:

BulkInsertList:

```
[
    {
    fieldOne:val,
    fieldTwo:val,
    fieldThree:val,
    fieldFour:val
    },
    {
    fieldOne:val,
    fieldTwo:val,
    fieldThree:val,
    fieldFour:val
    },
    {
    ..
    }
    ..,
]
```

Bulk write should Insert data  with createdOn timestamp,

expected result,

```
BulkInsertList:
[
    {
        fieldOne:val,
        fieldTwo:val,
        fieldThree:val,
        fieldFour:val,

        createdOn: Timestamp
    },
    {
        ..
    },
    {
        ..
    }
]
```